# validate multiple entities at once before saving

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm just finding out about CakePHP3 and got stuck on the following problem:
In my code I am trying to save multiple entities at once through a transaction as explained in the docs (http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#changing-accessible-fields).
Now I would like to validate all entities during (or before) the transaction. I thought it might be possible to do something like this:

```
$entities = $table->newEntities($newEntities);
$result = $table->connection()->transactional(function () use ($table, $entities) {
    foreach ($entities as $entity) {
        if(!$table->save($entity)) {
            return array(
                'success' => false,
                'errors'  => $entity->errors(),
            );
        }
    }
    return array(
        'success' => true,
    );
});
```

The `$newEntities` variable is an array with some invalid data (for testing purpose). I was hoping to get errors in the `$result` variable and that the transaction wouldn't execute, but the transaction does executes and I get an SQL error instead of the Entity's error.

Another way of doing this would be to loop over all the entities and individually validate them, but it seems like there should be an easier way.

To simply get to the point: is there a way to validate multiple entities at once?

Comment: Are you talking about [**validation, or application rules**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/validation.html#validation-vs-application-rules)? The former is being applied in your `Table::newEntities()` call.

Comment: You're a champ! I already got the errors after the ->newEntities() method, didn't realise they were in the returned array. Thanks!